# YouTube videos won't play when DaVinci Resolve is open

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, alsa

#### The problem

Imported a video on DaVinci Resolve Studio it and it seemed to playback fine. However, whenever I tried to watch any video on YouTube after playing a video on DaVinci Resolve, it wouldn't work unless I closed DR.

#### My configuration

- Arch Linux
- Using PulseAudio
- NVidia GPU + Intel CPU on an Acer Nitro 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The solution

Use [DaVinci Resolve Checker](https://github.com/Ashark/davinci-resolve-checker) and check if it detects any problem.

If it says everything is fine but you still have the problem, [do as the Arch Wiki says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DaVinci_Resolve) and make a file called `asound.conf` on `/etc/` with the following content:

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

The goal is to make DR use PulseAudio interface instead of trying to use ALSA directly. I believe it was getting exclusive control of ALSA and then preventing applications that go through PulseAudio from accessing ALSA.
I suspected the problem had to do with audio drivers since I had a similar problem with Reaper before. This solution worked for me.